# Trouble submitting JSON to airtable via nextjs route.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, airtable, radix-ui

I'm trying to send data to airtable api via next js with the app route.

I'm using const data to store my json object.

When I send `body: JSON.stringify({ fields: testData }),`

I add a row to my airtable base, but no data.

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

```
//route.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const data = await req.json();
    console.log(data);
    // This is what I'm recieving back from the console. but it's still not working. testData is working.
    // {
    //   Name: 'Test',
    //   Company: 'con',
    //   Challenge: 'dasd',
    //   Email: 'connor.forsyth@email.com',
    //   Phone: '234234'
    // }
    const testData = {
      Name: "John",
      Company: "Fast Company",
      Challenge: "Here is my challenge",
      Email: "john@email.com",
      Phone: "+61400891285",
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appiQwkJeriH8srVq/Entries",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.AIRTABLE_TOKEN}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fields: testData }), // Airtable expects a "fields" object
      },
    );

    return NextResponse.json({ fields: testData }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // ---> I want to see what this prints server side, in your terminal
    const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unexpected Error";
    return NextResponse.json({ message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-form": "^0.0.3",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "vaul": "^0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
```

I expect a row with the data from my form to submit to airtable.

I can log my form to the console on the server, and submit dummy data no problem.